# How to change src in iFrame on user clicks ??

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I am a newbie with coding php or js. 
So please advise me if I am asking the question the wrong way.

I would like to be able to pass and embed URL address from a link into the src="URL embedded here" of an iFrame. The page with the link has links with a company name displayed, the user will click the link and a new .php page will be displayed with an iFrame that displays the actual website of that company within our site. So... for example... on the index page, the user clicks "Goodyear" and it launches a .php page containing the Goodyear website displayed within the iFrame. Now... I have about 20+ vendor links and am trying to avoid 20+ individual html or php pages to display that data. Especially since the vendor list will change often. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. The pages that I am referring to are http://seindl.com/index.php where you can see the appropriate URL's in the href elements; and the resulting linked to page http://seindl.com/vendor.php that currently displays a static Kuriyama.com website.

Comment: http://seindl.com/index.php this link is not working...

Comment: do you want to change iframe url on click event?

Comment: @RahulKaushik I apologize. I have uploaded the index.php

Comment: @DushyantJoshi Yes, i do want to change the URL within the iFrame on the click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appned id of vendor to the url like below on index.php page:

```
vendor.php?id=10
```

And then on vendor.php file, base on the id (use $_REQUEST['id'] to get id) you can put the url of the vendor.

```
$id =  $_REQUEST['id'];

if($id == 10){
$vendorSiteUrl = "http://vendorsiteurl.com";
}

....

<iframe src="<?php echo $vendorSiteUrl;?>"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where do I place the $id = bit of code on the page? Thank you so much!

Comment: I have implemented the code, but the $id = bit of code is showing at the top of the page in the header area, which is where i placed the code; and the iframe is not displaying anything.

Comment: Put this code in php tag like below:

<?php
$id =  $_REQUEST['id'];

if($id == 10){
$vendorSiteUrl = "http://vendorsiteurl.com";
}
?>

Comment: Thank you! I got it to work. Now I am looking at how to format the continuation of the elseif for the remaining url's in the php tag. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 1):

Well if you have list of links, you do not need jquery or javascript to change the iFrame src. For example, if you have iframe like this:

```
<iframe name="frame1" id="frame1" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

Simply creating links like this:

```
<a href="http://something.com" target="frame1">LINK</a>
```

will open the page in iFrame (based on `target` attribute of the link, which must match the iframe `name`).

If you really need to do it with jQuery, you can try something like:

```
$('#frame1').attr('src','http://something.com');
```

Or with javascript without libraries:

```
document.getElementById('frame1').src = 'http://something.com';
```

Which will also change the page open in the frame.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed responses. I will try your initial suggestion first.

Comment: YES, it works. Is there a way to make the "target" value actually to go to another page that has the iframe coding on it, instead on the same, original, page? Thank you so much thus far!

Comment: Menu is on one page and iframe is on another?

Comment: yes, the link is on the index page... while the iframe is on another.

Comment: Well are both pages open at the same time?

Comment: no, the link launches a new replacement page with the iframe.

Comment: Well then, you would need to pass parameter to another page which then creates iframe accordingly. This can be done in pure javascript, or something server-side, like php. However, that is totally another question imho, which you will need to ask again.

Comment: Thank you. I do think you are right. @RahulKaushik made a suggestion below that makes sense to me logically. I just don't know where to put the $id =  $_REQUEST['id'];

if($id == 10){
$vendorSiteUrl = "http://vendorsiteurl.com";
}

Comment: That is PHP and the fact that you see the code in your browser probably means that you are putting it inside HTML page.

Comment: Actually, it is on a php page. I put it in the <Head> section, as I didn't know where to put it on the page. you can actually see the page at [link](http://seindl.com/vendor.php)